# I am not getting the CPU Temerature

Tags: graphics, bios, temperature, lm-sensors

I have a  AMD Ryzen 7 7700X, I din't know it has integrated graphics, otherwise I wouldn't buy it. Anyway, I try to get the temerature reading an this is what I get with sensors.

```
amdgpu-pci-1700
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:      835.00 mV 
vddnb:         1.02 V  
edge:         +45.0°C  
PPT:          20.02 W  

nvme-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +37.9°C  (low  = -20.1°C, high = +83.8°C)
                       (crit = +88.8°C)
ERROR: Can't get value of subfeature temp3_min: I/O error
ERROR: Can't get value of subfeature temp3_max: I/O error
Sensor 2:     +50.9°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)

nvme-pci-1100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +44.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +83.8°C)
                       (crit = +83.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +44.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +40.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
```

[image]

But in BIOS (MSI X670-P) I see the temperature of the CPU and if I diactivate the integrated graphic the amdgpu-pci-1700 is gone. I simply don't understand this?  Does that mean I cannot have a temperature reading without the integrated graphic activated?

Comment: Would seem so but that is a hardware question nothing to do with the OS. You are in the BIOS.